# How to detect edge of object using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to use OpenCV to measure size of filament ( that plastic material used for 3D printing)

What I am trying to do is measuring filament size ( that plastic material used for 3D printing ). The idea is that I use led panel to illuminate filament, then take image with camera, preprocess the image, apply edge detections and calculate it's size. Most filaments are fine made of one colour which is easy to preprocess and get fine results.

The problem comes with transparent filament. I am not able to get useful results. I would like to ask for a little help, or if someone could push me the right directions. I have already tried cropping the image to heigh that is a bit higher than filament, and width just a few pixels and calculating size using number of pixels in those images, but this did not work very well. So now I am here and trying to do it with edge detections

- works well for filaments of single colour
- not working for transparent filament

Code below is working just fine for common filaments, the problem is when I try to use it for transparent filament. I have tried adjusting tresholds for Canny function. I have tried different colour-spaces. But I am not able to get the results.

Images that may help to understand:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EECrh.jpg

```
image = cv.imread("../images/img_fil_2.PNG")  # load image

gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert image to grayscale

edges = cv.Canny(gray, 100, 200)  # detect edges of image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assumption that the images are taken under the same conditions.

Your main problem is that the reflections in the transparent filament are detected as edges. But, since the image is relatively simple, without any other edges, you can simply take the upper and the lower edge, and measure the distance between them.

A simple way of doing this is to take 2 vertical lines (e.g. image sides), find the edges that intersect the line (basically traverse a column in the image and find edge pixels), and connect the highest and the lowest points to form the edges of the filament. This also removes the curvature in the filament, which I assume is not needed for your application.

You might want to use 3 or 4 vertical lines, for robustness.